# using colors in calculated member

Tags: colors, mdx

Im using this query in MDX for a calculate measure

topcount(nonempty([StatusPlanes].[Status].Status.members,[Measures].[Planes]),1)(0).member_caption

this will bring me this result

Dimension1     Measure
Center 1     'Status 1' ---> i want this text blue
Center 2     'Status 2' ---> i want this text in red
Center 3     'Status 3'
Center 4     'Status 2'

the thing I want to do is to add some color depending on the status... is this possible in mdx???

thank you in advance

Adriana

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color with code similar to that in [this blog post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2007/07/28/red-color-for-negative-numbers-in-analysis-services-2005.aspx)

The format of the color property is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145991.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CELL PROPERTIES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145573.aspx).

The property you are looking for is FORE_COLOR

However, take into account that your front-end tool must support it (not all of them do)